# How to add Boolean Button for a django model BooleanField so that a normal user can set the value as true or false?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am making a Task Management To Do web app..My code is working upto the level that a user can add task after logging in and the task alongwith the foreign key user gets stores to UserTask Model which contain 4 fields including User(F.K.),Label,Due Date,Status(Boolean). The last three field are entered while adding a task by the user however I need my status field (which gets displayed in the task.html alongwith other fields)  such that it can be toggled between true or false (task completed or not) as a checkList preferably.

How can i do that in django 3?

My models.py,forms.py,views.py and tasks.html are as follows:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class UserCustom(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    profile_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username   #user os object defined above

class UserTask(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label=models.CharField(max_length=264)
    date=models.DateField()
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.label)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import DateField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taskApp.models import UserCustom,UserTask
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password')

class UserCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=UserCustom
        fields=('profile_pic',)

class UserTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date=DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'required': 'required'}))
    class Meta():
        model=UserTask
        fields=('label','date','status')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from taskApp.forms import UserForm,UserCustomForm,UserTaskForm
from taskApp.models import UserCustom,UserTask
#below libraries required for login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'taskApp/index.html')

@login_required
def add_task(request):
    added=False

    if request.method == "POST":
        task_form=UserTaskForm(data=request.POST)

        if task_form.is_valid():
            task=task_form.save(commit=False)
            #print("NAME:"+str(request.user))
            task.author=request.user
            task.save()
            added=True

        else:
            print(task_form.errors)


    else: #no request=POST yet
        task_form=UserTaskForm()

    return render(request,'taskApp/addTask.html',{'added':added,'task_form':task_form})

@login_required
def my_task(request):
    task_obj=UserTask.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return render(request,'taskApp/task.html',{'task_obj':task_obj})


@login_required
def user_logout(request):  #only login users can logout
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def register(request):

    registered=False

    if request.method == "POST":

        user_form=UserCustomForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user=user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered=True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

    else: #no request=POST yet
        user_form=UserCustomForm()
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request,'taskApp/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered })



def user_login(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')  #name of element
        password=request.POST.get('password')

        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('taskApp:myTask')) #myTask is the name of url , go to urls.py
            else:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")

        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed!")
            print("Username: {} and password {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details supllied!")

    else:
        return render(request,'taskApp/login.html',{})
```

task.html

```
{% extends "taskApp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  {% if task_obj %}
      <table>
          <thead>
              <th>Label</th>
              <th>Due Date</th>
              <th>Status</th>
          </thead>
          {% for t in task_obj %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ t.label }}</td>
                <td>{{ t.date }}</td>
                <td>{{ t.status }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </table>
  {% else %}
      <p>NO TASKS FOUND</p>
  {% endif %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, but it is my understanding that you want the my_task view to have a way to toggle the status of the task that is displayed?

Comment: yes exactly that i want so that user can mark the status as completed which gets reflected back in the UserTask model in database i.e. when users mark the status on his page (completed) , 'status' field of UserTask  model in database gets set to True.